# Why Magento SOAP multiLocationInventoryStockList is not accepting any filter request?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, soap, c#

I am trying from magento soap to get info about inventory from individual "sku", but object "multiLocationInventoryStockList" is getting me back result from all locations Id's.

Here is my code in C#:

Filter:

```
string locationid = "1";

filters filter = new filters
        {
            complex_filter = new[]
            {
                new complexFilter
                {
                    key = "sku",
                    value = new associativeEntity { key = "eq", value = "123456-Test"}
                }
            }
        };
```

Then call for results:

```
var list = client.multiLocationInventoryStockList(sessionID, locationid, filter);
```

Now this same filter works fine for other objects e.g. catalogProductList, but not for multiLocationInventoryStockList. I can't find any documentation for this object that is requesting diffrent keys and values in filter.

I am using magento 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That **multiLocationInventoryStockList** doesn't seem to be a valid operation in Magento default **wsdl.xml** files

> app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/wsdl.xml

If this is provided by a 3rd party extension or module, as it seems, you'd better contact their technical support, or at least provide related code, so user can check it

**update**

After a bit of Google... Maybe this would be the right place to ask for support?

https://github.com/DemacMedia/Magento-Multi-Location-Inventory/issues